# Azure Mobile Apps custom authentication

Tags: azure, authentication, xamarin

I'm trying to implement custom auth using the `LoginAsync(string provider, JObject token)` overload of MobileServiceClient. I'have a custom auth controller like this

```
[MobileAppController]
public class CustomAuthController : ApiController
{
   public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Post([FromBody] JObject assertion)
  {
    ...
  }
}
```

and inside backend startup I set the route

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomAuth", ".auth/login/CustomAuth",new { controller = "CustomAuth" });
```

On client side the call is:

```
var credentials = new JObject
{
    ["email"] = username,
    ["password"] = password
};            
MobileServiceUser user;
try
{
    user = await MobileService.LoginAsync("CustomAuth", credentials);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    throw;
}
```

I think all it's correct but I cannot call the controller with LoginAsync method (in debug I set a breakpoint on first instruction of controller).
And I connot even see the exception because the catch block it's never reached.
But I can send request to CustomAuthController using Postman for example and in this case the debug breakpoint is reached...
I don't understand why!!
I'm trying to debug LoginAsync (that uses MobileServiceTokenAuthentication) decompiled code without success...please help!
On backend side my custom authentication is made with auth0 delegation api.

Comment: Can you show more of your client code? If you can't debug your login method I have a feeling you are not properly awaiting that method.

Comment: mmm I think not because the above client call is awaited inside a method that returns a task, the signature is `async Task<MobileServiceUser> LoginAsync(string username, string password)` and all the chain always returns a task...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to remove the `[MobileAppController]` attribute from the controller code. This attribute adds a requirement that the call include a version header, and the client SDK does not send these for the login methods. Alternatively you could use a delegating handler on the client to inject this header, but the server-side change will involve less code. In the context of custom auth, the attribute isn't providing any benefit that I can think of, so it should be safe to remove.

Comment: Thanks Matt, I had not noticed this particular and rightly this handler should not be marked with the attribute.