# Azure Mobile Apps Custom Authentication Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Tags: c#, android, .net, azure

I am trying to implement custom authentication but I am gettig the same error all time in my client.

I used this sources:

- https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-apps-net-server/wiki/Local-development-and-debugging-the-Mobile-App-.NET-server-backend
- https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-dotnet-backend-how-to-use-server-sdk/#how-to-work-with-authentication
- [Azure Mobile Apps custom authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37851855/azure-mobile-apps-custom-authentication)

Error:

> {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
>     at Microsoft.WindowsAzure.MobileServices.MobileServiceAuthentication+d__25.MoveNext () [0x0009a] in :0 
>   --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
>     at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/exceptionservices/exceptionservicescommon.cs:143 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x00047] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:187 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0002e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:156 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) [0x0000b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:128 
>     at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3819/96c7ba6c/source/mono/mcs/class/referencesource/mscorlib/system/runtime/compilerservices/TaskAwaiter.cs:357 
>     at ToDoItemSample.Droid.MainActivity+d__1.MoveNext () [0x0009c] in C:\Users\flori\Desktop\ToDoItemSample_Xamarin_Forms\Droid\MainActivity.cs:43 }

My code on client:

```
var credentials = new JObject
{
    ["email"] = "xyz",
    ["password"] = "password"
};

try
{
    user = await TodoItemManager.DefaultManager.CurrentClient.LoginAsync("CustomAuth", credentials);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{

}
```

---

CustomAuthController.cs

```
public class CustomAuthController : ApiController
{
    public IHttpActionResult Post([FromBody] JObject assertion)
    {
        if (isValidAssertion(assertion))
        {
            var token = AppServiceLoginHandler.CreateToken(
                new[] {new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Sub, assertion["email"].ToString())},
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"],
                ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"],
                TimeSpan.FromHours(24));

            return Ok(new LoginResult
            {
                AuthenticationToken = token.RawData,
                User = new LoginResultUser { UserId = assertion["email"].ToString() }
            });
        }

        return Unauthorized();
    }

    private static bool isValidAssertion(JObject assertion)
    {
        // this is where we would do checks agains a database

        return true;
    }
}
```

---

Startup.cs:

```
public static void ConfigureMobileApp(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        var config = new HttpConfiguration();

        //For more information on Web API tracing, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=620686 
        config.EnableSystemDiagnosticsTracing();
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute("CustomAuth", ".auth/login/CustomAuth", new {controller = "CustomAuth" });

        new MobileAppConfiguration()
            .UseDefaultConfiguration()
            .ApplyTo(config);

        new DbMigrator(new Migrations.Configuration())
            .Update();

        var settings = config
            .GetMobileAppSettingsProvider()
            .GetMobileAppSettings();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(settings.HostName))
            app.UseAppServiceAuthentication(new AppServiceAuthenticationOptions
            {
                SigningKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SigningKey"],
                ValidAudiences = new[] {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidAudience"]},
                ValidIssuers = new[] {ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ValidIssuer"]},
                TokenHandler = config.GetAppServiceTokenHandler()
            });
        app.UseWebApi(config);
    }
```

Web.config

```
appSettings>
<!-- Use these settings for local development. After publishing to your
Mobile App, these settings will be overridden by the values specified
in the portal. -->
<add key="SigningKey" value="********************" />
<add key="ValidAudience" value="https://*****.azurewebsites.net/" />
<add key="ValidIssuer" value="https://*****.azurewebsites.net/" />
```

I also use local debugging. 
Interresting is when I deploy it the to azure cloud and I use remote debugging my breakpoint get hit, when I use local debuggig my breakpoint won't get hit.

**Edit**
I have found a solution at:

- [Azure Mobile Apps - Custom authentication - Unable to login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38326019/azure-mobile-apps-custom-authentication-unable-to-login)

You need to publish it to azure also if you debug locally, because the authentication runs at azure. I think that is also the reason you can debug this method only with remote debugging.

Comment: As I know, the similar issue link you provided, which is a problem of uppercase/lowercase properties provided in a Anonymous Class. In your code, you returned the class `LoginResult` as the response. Do you mean that this similar issue directs you to resolve your issue?

Comment: Yes the problem was because of uppercase/lowercase, my problem was also I was not able to set a breakpoint at the api call, because of the remote authentication process. If you want to debug this api call you need to use remote debugging in the cloud. I am not an expert, thats just what I think.